Slow Camera with YoloV5
I’m working with a Jetson Orin Nano and a Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2, aiming to run YOLOv5 for real-time image processing. I’ve tried using the following code, but the camera feed is extremely slow and laggy, which I didn’t expect from this setup. How to improve this?
Here is my code:
import cv2
import torch
import numpy as np  

# Load YOLOv5 model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')

# GStreamer pipeline for CSI camera
def gstreamer_pipeline(
    capture_width=1920, 
    capture_height=1080,
    display_width=960,
    display_height=540,
    framerate=30,
    flip_method=2,
):
    return (
        "nvarguscamerasrc ! "
        "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), "
        "width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! "
        "nvvidconv flip-method=%d ! "
        "video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! "
        "videoconvert ! "
        "video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink drop=True"
        % (
            capture_width,
            capture_height,
            framerate,
            flip_method,
            display_width,
            display_height,
        )
    )

# Live video capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gstreamer_pipeline(), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Unable to open camera. Please check the connection.")
    exit()

while cap.isOpened():
    cv2.namedWindow("Detect", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if not ret:
        print("Unable to retrieve frame.")
        break

    # Make predictions using YOLOv5
    results = model(frame)
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render())) 

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Interestingly, when I use the following pipeline, the camera runs much faster:
import cv2
gst_str = "nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Unable to open camera")
else:
    print("Camera opened")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Unable to retrieve frame")
        break

    cv2.imshow("CSI Camera", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I want to use YOLO for real-time image processing and eventually build a training algorithm. I’m open to suggestions for optimizing the current setup or switching to a different YOLO variant or any other approach suitable for the Jetson Orin Nano.

Have you done any instrumentation to learn how much time the YOLO model takes for each frame?  What leads you to believe it should be able to keep up in real-time?  The website implies about 100ms per frame when run on a CPU, which is 10 FPS.  https://docs.ultralytics.com/models/yolov5/#supported-tasks-and-modes
